# I don't have a monitor.xml in Lubuntu 18.04, where are my settings saved?

Tags: 18.04, lubuntu, monitor, settings

I have found multiple references on this site and others to a ~/.config/monitors.xml that's supposed to be what saves your monitor settings. However, when I list the contents of the directory, I get this:

[image: Terminal Output]

Then, if I try to bring up the contents of this supposed file, I get this:

[image: Nanoed File]

So clearly the file does not exist to any capacity, at least in that directory on this system. My question is where could this file be then? I need to know so that I can have it edited when need be. I'd appreciate any help with this. I have no issues saving monitor settings through the GUI, so it has to be somewhere.